# Certain application categories, such as "Watch Application", cannot be launched by "Run As” in tizen

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

I have created new sample tizen native project using template “Basic UI”.But whenever I’m trying to run it on watch emulator 2.3.1 it is giving me message as”Certain application categories, such as "Watch Application", cannot be launched by "Run As”.”.Please help if anyone have idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've used `<watch-application>` element in the manifest file of your application. Please use `<ui-application>` element instead of that for UI application and also have a look in the following link for more details:

[Manifest Text Editor](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4/org.tizen.devtools/html/native_tools/manifest_text_editor_n.htm#ui)

Answer (score 0):

Your watch application is installed as "watch"
You can see it by long pressing your watch and go to the last watch template which must be yours.